# preg_match function always returns true value

Tags: php, mysqli

I used the preg_match function and it works fine when a match occur but it also returns true when a match does not occurs.
the code i am using is:

```
if (preg_match('/[slider]/',$value)) {
//return $kk=preg_match('/[slider]/',$value);
$out=delete_all_between('[', ']', $value);

$xx=explode("[slider id=",$value);

    $yy=$xx[1];
    $zz=str_replace(']', '', $yy);
    $slider_query=mysqli_query($con,"select images_id from sliders where id='$zz'");
    $slider_query_result=mysqli_fetch_array($slider_query);
    $images_id=$slider_query_result['images_id'];
    $split_images_id=explode(",",$images_id);
    $data="";
    foreach($split_images_id as $si)
    {
    $image_query=mysqli_query($con,"select image_url from gallery where id='$si' ");
    $image_query_result=mysqli_fetch_array($image_query);
    $image=$image_query_result['image_url'];
    $data.='<li><a href="#"><img src="uploads/'.$image.'" height="80px" width="80px"></a></li>';
    }
    return $out.$data;
}
 else
 {
     return $value;
 }
}
```

once `$value` contains the `[slider]` and second time &value does not contain `[slider]`
please any solution and feel free for any doubt.

Answer (score 1):

`[slider]` is a character class, meaning, `preg_match()` will return a truthy value if **any of the characters** in the list are found in the supplied string. You need to explicity escape the characters `[` and `]` to match the string `[slider]`:

```
if (preg_match('/\[slider\]/', $value)) {
    # code...
}
```

Comment: @Amy-Amy: You are using `preg_match('/[slider]/',$value)`, but you need to use **`preg_match('/\[slider\]/',$value)`** instead. Note how `[` and `]` are escaped.

Comment: @Amy-Amy: Glad I could help. I suggest you go through a basic regex tutorial first, so you could avoid such minor errors in future. Cheers!

Comment: your condition is working fine but the function in the true condition is not working now...